# I don’t get a notification when I get a new text message (iPhone 5, iOS 12)

Tags: iphone, messages, notifications, alert

For some time now I have not been receiving notifications when getting a text message on my iPhone. Notifications for all other apps work fine, and I have checked that notifications for messages are switched on in settings.

I have tried turning it off and on again.

I’m receiving messages in Messages just fine. The app icon shows a red ”1” when a new text message has come. It’s the alert sound and vibration I’m missing. I am signed in on my Mac with the same ID. I tried turning the computer off but it didn’t help.

I don’t get notifications from anyone, so it’s not contact-specific "Hide Alerts" unfortunately.

I do get a notification if I am inside the app, but not otherwise. Can you help me?

[image: enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luZTO.png)]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Messages Notifications screen?  Also, do you have any other device turned on that's signed in with the same Apple ID?  It's possible that another device is getting the notifications first.

Comment: I am signed in on my mac computer, but I don’t receive text messages on it. I’ve added a screen shot. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Try turning your Mac off and then send a test text.  You're not having problems receiving messages in Messages, right?  It's just the notifications?

Comment: Exactly. I’m receiving messages in Messages just fine. The app icon shows a red ”1” when a new text message has come. It’s the alert sound and vibration I’m missing. I tried turning the computer off but it didn’t help :/

Comment: It could be contact-specific notification turn-off. Tap the username of the "1" message and see if "Hide Alerts" is off.

Comment: I don’t get notifications from anyone, so it’s not contact-specific unfortunately.

Comment: just found out i have same issue.  I tried sending myself a test message from my desktop computer.  I got the message but no notification.

Comment: A few moments ago I started getting notifications again. Don't know what happened, so I don't have a solution...but thought I should write and let you know that it's not a problem for me anymore.